# What is the naming convention for a Type and the Class that implements it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have a class *DropdownItem* which creates a blueprint for a dropdown option.

```
class DropdownItem {
  value: string;
  name: string;
  ....
}
```

Is there any other option that just naming it *DropdownItemInterface*.?

```
interface DropdownItemInterface  { // ???
  value: string;
  name: string;
}
```

What is the best practice, or is there one?

Comment: Why do you need that? `DropdownItem` both refers to a class *and a type*.

Comment: You are right, in this particular case it's redundant, although typescript won't show me the insights of it if I use a class as type.

Comment: @George.S - It should. The playground does for me. If I type `const item: DropdownItem = {` then Ctrl+Space shows `value` and `name`  choices for me to pick.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am using that in VSCode. It is a just code editor feature, I can get by with it at least showing what class type it refers to.

Comment: @George.S - I think I must not be understanding what you're referring to. Works for me in vscode, too. Anyway, happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I got it working for me too. Thank you again, Happy coding!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convention is to just use the class name as the type. As in most (but not all) languages with classes, the class defines both the implemenation *and* the interface. You *can* define a separate interface, but it's not required and standard practice is not to do so.

Note that in TypeScript, things are assignment-compatible even if they don't have a type relationship via declared interfaces. For instance:

```
class DropdownItem {
  value: string = "";
  name: string = "";
}

function example(item: DropdownItem): void {
    //...
}

const item1 = {value: "x", name: "foo"};

example(item1);  // No error here, even though `item1` is not
                 // declared of type DropdownItem
```

In fact, what you use as a `DropdownItem` only has to have `value` and `name` with the right types, even if it has other things as well:

```
const item2 = {value: "y", name: "bar", other: 42};

example(item2);  // No error here, it's okay that it has an
                 // extra property
```

[Examples on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiBOB7ADgE0QdwHYEkAuApgLbQDeAUNNAG5ggCuBAXNBHvAJZYDm0AvNABEggNyVoWMEWat2XXgOFiAvuXIAzelmB4OiLNAIAPKchAEAFB0JEWCFOmz5iAShbVEHVGXFUA9H4AdMHkquTA+mzQ1sQAjPxktAwygkaCADQSUinqiIiCymLkxqbmVjaxLiL+ftAAcoiG8Ejw0AAWBPAEmQTUBAZ4bYj03G3QAAYxRLHj0TBYiHi+VCurawHQqASgYF3eiOrQeACeyARwSGiYuDZqEVhRUwBMCaRJjCyCxxlZ0p8ARrsfosOvAWAAWJ6FNQlIhmSzPKo1eqNTotdqdbrRPAAchgiAA1mBjkc2mA8Nj2pBoGAsMs1gzkcZ2GBoMhLp0TkA).

---

If you **do** decide to have a separate interface, I don't think there's any one standard way of naming the interface. Most interfaces I've seen in TypeScript are just named in the normal way, without any particular indicator that they're interfaces. On those rare occasions when an indicator is used, it's typically an `I` prefix, e.g. `IDropDownItem`, but I suspect I've mostly seen that in code written by people used to it from other languages or (showing my age) COM.

Comment: Well, I had a feeling that should be it. Thank you for explanation

Comment: Sidenote: I sometimes create a type/combination if I don't want a class: `type User = { ... }; const User = { create(): User { ... }, ... };`